# Interpretation of Huygens Expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value, history

Christiaan Huygens wrote in "*Libelus de Ratiociniis in Ludo Alae*"
(can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220216095038/https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoyle/docs/huygens/huygens.pdf) - page 2, *Postulat*) :

> That any one Chance or Expectation to win any thing
> is worth just such a Sum, as wou’d procure in the same Chance and Expectation
> at a fair Lay. As for Example, if any one shou’d put 3 Shillings in one Hand,
> without telling me know which, and 7 in the other, and give me Choice of
> either of them; I say, it is the same thing as if he shou’d give me 5 Shillings;
> because with 5 Shillings I can, at a fair Lay, procure the same even Chance or
> Expectation to win 3 or 7 Shillings.

I know the modern meaning of "expectation" but I am more interested in the original meaning Huygens assigned to it.

Unfortunately I cannot understand what he wrote.

How are the two games described similar?

Comment: There are votes to close as off-topic, I see this as clearly on-topic. But it needs some more info, like a reference/link for the citation

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have added a link for the citation. Is there anything else I should add to this post to make it more complete?

Comment: Even in the modern sense, the expectations of the two games are both 5 shillings.  The modern sense was created by Fermat and Pascal in correspondence several years before Huygens' book, which was written with knowledge of what F&P had done.  The quoted passage makes it clear Huygens had the same concept.